# How to write JOIN QUERY for 4 tables in the below condition

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, left-join

I have 4 tables `ACCOUNTS_TABLE` , `LINKS_TABLE`, `GROUPS_TABLE`, `KEYS_TABLE` 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need to get `all accounts details` which is of acct_type `xx` with `count of Links, groups& keywords` . I have tried this query but it gives all `count as 0`

```
SELECT 
    acc.acct_id, acc.acct_type, count(link.id) as link_count, link.account, 
    groups.camp_id, count(groups.id) as group_count, count(keyword.key_id) as key_count 

FROM ".ACCOUNTS_TABLE." as acc  
    LEFT JOIN ".LINKS_TABLE." as link ON link.account=acc.acct_id AND acct_type='xx' 
    LEFT JOIN  ".GROUPS_TABLE." as groups ON  groups.camp_id=link.id 
    LEFT JOIN ".KEYS_TABLE." as keyword ON keyword.camp_id=link.id 

GROUP BY acc.acct_id
```

My required output should be like this
[image]

Any one please help me to slove this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use COUNT(DISTINCT ....).

```
SELECT acc.acct_id, COUNT(DISTINCT link.id), COUNT(DISTINCT groups.id), COUNT(DISTINCT keyword.key_id)
FROM ACCOUNTS_TABLE acc
LEFT OUTER JOIN LINKS_TABLE link ON link.account = acc.acct_id AND acct_type = 'advertiser'
LEFT OUTER JOIN GROUPS_TABLE groups ON  groups.camp_id = link.id 
LEFT JOIN KEYS_TABLE keyword ON keyword.id = link.id 
WHERE acc.acct_type = 'xx'
GROUP BY acc.acct_id
```

EDIT

Amended to use the updated join conditions, etc:-

```
SELECT acc.acct_id, acc.acct_type, COUNT( DISTINCT link.id ) , COUNT( DISTINCT groups.id ) , COUNT( DISTINCT keyword.key_id ) 
FROM ACCOUNTS_TABLE acc
LEFT OUTER JOIN LINKS_TABLE link ON link.account = acc.acct_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN GROUPS_TABLE groups ON groups.camp_id = link.id
LEFT JOIN KEYS_TABLE keyword ON keyword.camp_id=link.id 
WHERE acc.acct_type = 'xx'
GROUP BY acc.acct_id, acc.acct_type
```

Comment: Still its giving all count as zero

Comment: when i omit `GROUP BY acc.acct_id` it gives the total count correctly. But i need toget all accounts seperatly!

Comment: The thing that seems to stop it bringing back useful data with your test data is that you have specified an acct_type of 'advertiser' in the join onto the link table. There are no matching records for this. Removing this gets some records. Also you have specified joining the key table using key_id and the link tables id. Do you want to join these on these or on camp_id which would make more sense?

Comment: Actually `xx` means `advertiser` in real records. I have updated my query in question. Thats not the problem

Comment: sorry, actually `keyword.id` is same as camp_id in real data key_id is different. i had given `keyword.id` not key_id (Now updated the query)

Comment: Changing those conditions and the query appears to work. What will not work is trying to bring back the groups.camp_id when you are doing a GROUP BY type query (you are doing a count of those, there are multiples of them for each acct_id)

Comment: This does give you the results you want it would seem.

Comment: with dummy values it works. But in server it gives all count as 0. In server there are  millions of records. Let me check whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT  ACC.Id
       ,( SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Links L WHERE L.AccountId = ACC.Id ) AS CountOfLinks
       ,( SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Groups G WHERE G.AccountId = ACC.Id ) AS CountOfGroups
FROM    ( SELECT Id FROM Accounts Acc WHERE Acc.Type = 'some type' ) ACC
```

Comment: Co related sub queries are VERY expensive.

Comment: @OlivierCoilland: You're right, you perfectly could do without.

Comment: Groups table has no accountID... `WHERE G.AccountId = ACC.Id `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  accounts_table.acct_id,
  accounts_table.acct_type,
  COUNT(DISTINCT links_table.id) AS link_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT groups_table.id) AS group_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT keys_table.key_id) AS key_count
FROM 
  accounts_table
LEFT JOIN 
  links_table
  ON links_table.account = accounts_table.acct_id
LEFT JOIN 
  groups_table 
  ON groups_table.camp_id = links_table.id
LEFT JOIN 
  keys_table 
  ON keys_table.camp_id = links_table.id
WHERE 
  acct_type = 'xx'
GROUP BY 
  accounts_table.acct_id,
  accounts_table.acct_type
ORDER BY 
  link_count DESC,
  group_count DESC,
  key_count DESC
```

Edited answer to match updated question - this should do what you've asked for.

This should do what you've asked for, SQL fiddle here - [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b6a/20](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/757de/8)

Comment: This is the same query which i gave.

Answer (score 0):

I've rejigged your code a bit (see below) for a few reasons:

1. It's helpful (for me anyway) to write my SELECT statements always in a certain way - with anything that is not being grouped placed first, and ideally putting things in same order as my JOINs and doing the same in my GROUP BY
2. I put anything which restricts my FROM table into the WHERE not the JOIN to make it clearer what I'm trying to do and also to make it easier to modify later on.
3. I also like to ensure it's well laid out to make it easier to scan for issues.

Take this rearranged query and read through it to make sure you are getting the behaviour you're expecting.

PS I'm not sure about your table names and quotation style - I usually use back ticks (`) and would never put dots (.) in my table names.  If you put these in as placeholders that's fine but they could lead to trouble for you if they are real.

```
SELECT 
acc.acct_id, 
-- if you don't group by these then you need to remove them as they will just return the first values based on mysql behaviour
acc.acct_type, 
link.account,
groups.camp_id,
-- these counts will only count where an ID is present which seems like what you're after
count(link.id) as link_count, 
count(groups.id) as group_count, 
count(keyword.key_id) as key_count
FROM ".ACCOUNTS_TABLE." as acc  
LEFT JOIN ".LINKS_TABLE." as link ON link.account=acc.acct_id 

LEFT JOIN  ".GROUPS_TABLE." as groups ON  groups.camp_id=link.id 
LEFT JOIN ".KEYS_TABLE." as keyword ON keyword.id=link.id 

WHERE acct_type='advertiser' 

GROUP BY acc.acct_id,  
-- only use these if you intend to group by them  
acc.acct_type, 
link.account,
groups.camp_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT acct_type,
       count(acct_type),
       count(l.id),
       count(g.id),
       count(key_id)
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN links l ON (l.account = a.acct_id)
LEFT JOIN groups g ON (g.camp_id = l.id)
LEFT JOIN keysTable k ON k.group_id = g.id
GROUP BY acct_type HAVING acct_type = 'xx';
```

**SQL Fiddle Validated: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b6a/20**

Comment: I need to get all accounts details with counts seperatly. It just give the total count. ie, acc1 have 2 links 1 group and 3 keywords, acc2 have 3 links 3 groups and 1 keyword like wise